# Decidable formal language with a finite but non-computable size

Tags: computability, formal-languages, turing-machines, decidability

I'm looking for a formal language that has the following properties:

1. Contains finitely many words (and you can prove it).
2. Decidable/recursive (there's a Turing machine that always halts, that can determine whether any given word belongs to the language).
3. It's impossible to compute the exact number of words it contains. Meaning, even if you've already found all the words in the language, you can never know if there's another word that you just didn't try yet.

Such a language feels "illegal", but I didn't manage to disprove its existence.

Comment: Have you consulted with AI?

Comment: @Mikasa ChatGPT gave me wrong answers, and now says it's impossible but doesn't fully explain itself

Comment: Not sure I got this right, but it seems to me that you are looking for a finite set (of natural numbers) such that checking membership to this set is recursive but counting the exact number of elements is not. Such a set does not exist: if you know that your set is finite (say it is bounded by $N$), you can just check whether every number $\le N$ is in the set and count those that are. It does not matter that $N$ is not found computably, the algorithm still produces the correct answer, against the third requirement.

Comment: @Manlio Exactly, I'm looking for a finite collection (not necessarily a valid ZFC set), where you can prove there's a number $N$ bounding it, but you can never prove what $N$ is equal to. If you can't know $N$, you will pass it by without noticing.

Comment: If you can prove that $N$ exists, you can hardcode a sufficiently large one in your algorithm. You do not need to find $N$ computably. If you don't want to do so, then it seems that you are also asking for some uniformity condition: given *any* finite set, count the number of its elements. Then this is not computable (essentially for the reason you mentioned). However this is not a property of the single set, but a property of a collection of sets, i.e. there is a family of finite sets s.t. the function mapping each set in the family to the number of its elements is not computable.